OpenStreetMap admin_level relationships
I've been unable to develop the correct Overpass query to retrieve the parent admin_levels from a Wikidata id:
Overpass query for admin_level parents for an area
What I'd like is to start with a Wikidata id that is for admin_level 8 or 6 (or even 4) and have Overpass return all the parent admin_levels that Wikidata id's area falls into.
For example, Dallas, Texas (Q16557), falls into five different counties, which fall in the state of Texas, which falls in the United States.
Gainesville, Georgia (Q651051), is in Hall County, which is in Georgia, which is in the United States.
With Grzegorz Sapijaszko's assistance, I had developed the following query, which works for Dallas, Texas (Q16557), as intended (returns the five parent counties (admin_level 6), the state of Texas (admin_level 4), and the country of United States (admin_level 2):
[out:json];
area[wikidata=Q16557]->.a; // Q16557 = Dallas, Texas
(relation[wikidata][wikipedia](area.a); <<;)->.p;
relation.p[admin_level~"2|4|6"];
out geom;

https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/1UmC

However for Gainesville, Georgia (Q651051), it returns only Hall County (admin_level 6) but not Georgia (admin_level 4) or United States (admin_level 2):
[out:json];
area[wikidata=Q651051]->.a; // Q651051 = Gainesville, Georgia
(relation[wikidata][wikipedia](area.a); <<;)->.p;
relation.p[admin_level~"2|4|6"];
out geom;

https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/1UmD

I suspect it's not connecting Hall County (Q492012) with its parent state, Georgia, and this seems to verify that:
[out:json];
area[wikidata=Q492012]->.a; // Q492012 = Hall County, Georgia
(relation[wikidata][wikipedia](area.a); <<;)->.p;
relation.p[admin_level~"2|4|6"];
out geom;

https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/1UmJ

However, when I check Georgia (wikidata Q1428) for child counties using this query, it shows Hall County as being one:
[out:json];
area[wikidata=Q1428]->.a; // Q1428 = Georgia
relation[boundary~"administrative|census"][wikidata][wikipedia][admin_level~"6"](area.a);
out geom;

https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/1UmF

Is the problem in the query or the OSM tagging?
I've been referred to other tools, but I will not use this often so an Overpass API call is the best option for my application unless I can use Nominatim to achieve this, which I have not been able to search for admin_levels with.

Neither with query, neither with tagging. The << and >> operators goes up/down relation, not their areas. In first query (Q651051 = Gainesville, Georgia) it looks for all upper level relations to which it belong. The Hall County is found. However Hall county itself (https://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/1026132) doesn't belong to any upper level relation. On the other hand your last query (https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/1UmF) is looking for all admin relations within specific area, not by lower level relations.

The solution might be to look around for admin relations,  see: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Overpass_QL#Relative_to_other_elements_(around)

In fact the best solution would be to add all counties as subareas to Georgia state relation (https://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/161957). See Texas for difference (https://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/114690). And that's my last comment otherwise I will consider myself as spammer.

Thanks, Grzegorz -- I couldn't figure out where that was being traced through but I see it now.
I'm new to OSM, but if I were willing to add those subareas, any suggestions for where to look that explains how to add them?

If I may suggest: use JOSM and try to edit the relation.  General description: https://josm.openstreetmap.de/wiki/Help/Dialog/RelationEditor. Open Georgia's relation and add other relations (counties) as a members with subarea role. Check Texas how it's done. That's it :).

Thanks for all your help, Grzegorz!  I'll research it and I hope you'll be open to some follow up questions if necessary!
